# Passive mechanical system to direct force and displacement into different ropes - Can this even be? (Mechanical transistor with direct actuation)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machine-design, springs, pulleys

In this question I'd like to ask wether it is possible in general to build the following device. I don't come from an engineering background, so I'm probably not using the right words, but I'll try to describe what I mean:

It should be a passive mechanical system, connected to 2 ropes, and have an operating mechanism. In its default state, the system pulls rope 1 with a force X. When the operating mechanism
is acted on by a user with a force not bigger than X, the system shouldn't pull rope 1 at all anymore, but instead pull rope 2 with force X. The displacement of the ropes should match the displacement
of the operating mechanism in the beginning.
If this were electronics, I'd use a transistor, but it's supposed to be a mechanical system, with "direct actuation".
Is it possible to build something like this at all? What would be a good framework to find out wether this is possible at all?

Maybe to have a better understanding what this is meant for, I will now give a more detailed description of the application that I have in mind:

In a part of a device that I want to build (music-instrument), there are two levers. Both of them can be pulled out of their initial position. They are springloaded, so the amount of force required to pull them
out of their initial position is proportional to the displacement. For each of them seperately, you need an amount force X to hold them in their engaged position.
[image: Picture of the requirements]]
The working principle of the device requires that one of these levers is engaged anytime. One lever is engaged by default, and while the user pulling a trigger, the engagement switches:
When the trigger is pulled and held, lever 1 goes back into its initial position, and lever two is engaged. When the trigger is released, lever two is released as well, and lever one is
engaged again.

An easy way to implement this is to have a spring pull down lever 1, and let the trigger pull up lever 1, and at the same time pull down lever 2, via a system of rope and pulleys.
[[image: Implementation with shortcoming]][2
However, the spring needs to apply at least force X on lever 1 in the engaged position, to keep it there. Pulling lever 1 and the attached spring back into its initial position thus also
requires at least force X.
On top of that we also need force X to pull down lever 2. That means we need to apply force 2X on the trigger to change from lever 1 being engaged to lever 2 being engaged, although operating
each of them initially, one never needs more than force X
to have either one of them being engaged. Is there a smarter way to do this ?

Comment: It looks like something that would violate conservation of energy, at least if the strokes on lever 1 and lever 2 are unlimited, or even if they're no smaller than the stroke of your trigger.

Comment: @TimWescott can you elaborate? In the default (say displacement of the levers is d, and they are springloaded by an ideal spring) there is X*d/2 energy stored in lever 1, none in lever 2. In the triggered state, there is X*d/2 energy stored in lever 2, but none in lever 1. In the intermediate state, there is 2 * (X/2)*(d/2)/2 = X*d/4 energy stored in the springs.